# C# DllImport re-use with different DLL names

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have a native library that provides some functions, e.g.:

```c
CONSTBUFFER_HANDLE CONSTBUFFER_Create(const unsigned char* source, uint32_t size);
```

We'll call that "my_lib".

And from C# I can call it by exposing a DllImport like this:

```cs
[DllImport("my_dll1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern IntPtr CONSTBUFFER_Create(IntPtr source, uint size);
```

But, That native library is linked into multiple DLL's. And I have different C# code that interfaces with different DLL's, but this code in my_lib should be accessed via different DLL's depending on the C# module.

So for example I have C# module A which uses my_dllA.dll for all the native code, and my_dllA links to my_lib. And then C# module B uses my_dllB.dll for native code. I could have a my_lib.dll with this my_lib code, but the code in my_lib heap allocates memory which can be freed by other functions (basically it's reference counted in the C code). So I can run into issues if I call `CONSTBUFFER_Create` from my_lib.dll and then `some_other_function_which_frees_the_buffer` from my_dllA.dll.

I wanted to do something like this:

```cs
    internal class InteropDefs
    {
        protected const string nativeDll = "my_dllA.dll";

        [DllImport(nativeDll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        internal static extern IntPtr CONSTBUFFER_Create(IntPtr source, uint size);
    }

    internal class MyInterop
    {
        public IntPtr ConstbufferCreate(Intptr source, uint size)
        {
            return InteropDefs.CONSTBUFFER_Create(source, size);
        }
    }
```

And was hoping I could then re-use `InteropDefs` with different `nativeDll` values, but that doesn't seem possible:

```cs
    internal class InteropDefs
    {
        protected const string nativeDll = "my_dllA.dll";

        [DllImport(nativeDll, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        internal static extern IntPtr CONSTBUFFER_Create(IntPtr source, uint size);
    }

    internal class InteropDefsB : InteropDefs
    {
        nativeDll = "my_dllB.dll"; // somehow... doesn't seem to be any way to override this via static constructor or anything
    }

    internal class MyInterop<InteropDefsType> // I wish...
    {
        public IntPtr ConstbufferCreate(Intptr source, uint size)
        {
            return InteropDefsType.CONSTBUFFER_Create(source, size); // would be nice... but CS0704 error
        }
    }
```

So I guess the next best thing I can almost do is:

```cs
    internal class InteropDefsA
    {
        [DllImport("my_dllA.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        internal static extern IntPtr CONSTBUFFER_Create(IntPtr source, uint size);
    }

    // Don't love that all the signatures need to be repeated...
    internal class InteropDefsB
    {
        [DllImport("my_dllB.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        internal static extern IntPtr CONSTBUFFER_Create(IntPtr source, uint size);
    }

    internal class MyInterop
    {
        public IntPtr ConstbufferCreate(Intptr source, uint size)
        {
            return /*But how can I select InteropDefsA vs. InteropDefsB here?*/ .CONSTBUFFER_Create(source, size);
        }
    }
```

Is there anything that can be done like this, or am I stuck between either duplicating the function definitions for each DLL or using `GetProcAddress`?

Comment: you can always pass an extra param to check on which one to call? Or check the calling assembly to see which one to pick?

Comment: How would I pass an extra param? If the param is either `InteropDefsA` or `InteropDefsB`, then I can't do `x.CONSTBUFFER_Create` where x is one of those types because CS0704

Comment: For this type of setting (and if you don't have hundreds of methods like that), you could interop LoadLibrary + GetProcAddress => deletegate that you can call.

Comment: Subclassing wouldn't work when using `DllImport` as it requires `static` methods, and static is not inheritable.  So yeah LoadLibrary & GetProcAddress is your best bet. Or the more portable dotnet version, `NativeLibrary.Load` & `NativeLibrary.GetExport`